# Undefined reference to functions

Tags: c++, qt, sigar

I am trying out C++ and QT but I am walking against a wall trying to solve this problem as most of this is not familiar.

I am trying to use the SIGAR library but I am getting the following message from QT:

```
/home/john/QT-projects/WidgetFirst/mainwindow.cpp:37: error: undefined reference to `sigar_open'
```

With a couple of other functions being undefined.

My best  guess is that I didn't link something properly. The typhinting in the QT creator editor does work.

My .pro file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui webkitwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = WidgetFirst
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += "/home/john/Cpp libraries/sigar-master/include"

LIBS += -lboost_system -L"/home/john/Cpp libraries/sigar-master/src"

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += c++11
```

Could somebody tell me what I did wrong or what is missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any flags for linking the library...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What would that look like/what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is lib directory:

```
LIBS += -lboost_system -L"/home/john/Cpp libraries/sigar-master/lib" \
                       -lspecific_lib
```

Comment: I have the following directories: bindings, examples, include, src and test. Am I missing something? https://github.com/hyperic/sigar

Comment: Which directory contains *.lib binary files? Or maybe you have to build the library first?

Comment: There isn't. I though QT would do this for me?

Comment: Qt comes with own prebuilt libraries but how does it know about the rest of stuff (like SIGAR?) you try to link you project with?

Comment: I thought that the libs and includepath where the pointers for that?

Comment: It can be whatever. Linking with external libraries makes us to interfere with external project files as well and taking care of binary libs ready to link. Maybe you need to read some readme.txt or doc from that library.